# How do you find out which module is causing a redirect?

Tags: 7, redirection, debugging

I have a Drupal 7 site and have a bunch of custom modules installed. Currently when I hit a specific node/9283 it gets redirected to another page. I'm not sure which module is causing this redirect. I also check URL Alias and nothing is there for redirection. Its definitely something custom. How would you go about debugging this and figuring out which module/code/function is being loaded on this redirect to another page on the same site?

Comment: What kind of redirect is it? HTTP status code? Which one? Or JS? Or meta http-equiv? Or something else? And you have php module turned off, right?

Comment: im not sure how you would find the http status code. i turned off JS and it still redirects. so something on the backend is firing.

Comment: Use browser's console, network card? F12 in Chrome, for example? I don't want to sound mean, but that's kinda basic thing when developing and debugging interactions between server and client side.

Comment: oh yes.. thats true. i haven't used that tool in awhile. thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we're talking Drupal redirects (i.e. `drupal_goto` calls), the [Devel module](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) could help out here. In its settings it has a **Display redirection page** option that halts redirection for inspection.

You can use this in conjunction with a [`hook_drupal_goto_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_drupal_goto_alter/7) invocation to dump a stack trace on the redirection halt page to find the origin of the `drupal_goto` call.

```
function MYMODULE_drupal_goto_alter(&$path, &$options, &$http_response_code) {
  ddebug_backtrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I do is:

1. Clone site do dev environment
2. [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/)
3. Step by step execution

Simple, once you get your development environment up and running.

Comment: all these years. i have never setup xdebug before. i can't really clone the site that easily as its 30gb+... -_- .. i am working remotely off of the dev server. aside from xdebug how else would you debug this?

Comment: @duckx I usually omit media files when cloning - then 30GB shrinks to mere dozens of megabytes, usually. Aside from xdebug? I would try not to. Like, at all. Either it's my site and I know what I changed, or it's inherited and if it's owner does not want to provide infrastructure with dev environment, I don't want to work for him. But see my comment under your question.

Comment: i remember there was a way to do some type of back trace function finding thing by adding a function call in the index.php .. forgot how that was done. it was a long time ago.